# working with Q in django and combining QuerySet

Tags: python, django

There are two models `Orders` and `Clients`, when created, the same `related_uuid` is generated for each.
That is, they are so connected. When searching on the site, you need to find all occurrences in both models and display all `Orders`, including those where `related_uuid` occurs in the `Clients` model.

**models.py**

```
class Orders(models.Model):

    device = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    related_uuid = models.CharField(max_length=22, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.device

class Clients(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    related_uuid = models.CharField(max_length=22, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
def getQuery(self):
    search_query = self.request.GET.get('filter')
    results_query1 = Orders.objects.filter(Q(device__icontains=search_query))
    results_query2 = Clients.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=search_query))
    conds = Q(related_uuid__icontains=results_query1) | Q(related_uuid__icontains=related_query2)
    search_filter_three = Orders.objects.filter(conds)
    return search_filter_three
```

1. that is, I am looking for occurrences in both models.
2. then I try to select all inputs in the `Orders` model by the `related_uuid` field from both models.

**outputs** `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column (s)')`

Comment: Can you create a foreign key between `Orders` and `Clients`? That would make this easier.

Comment: Even if you can't use Foreign keys because of legacy database or something, you can always set [`ForeignKey.db_constraint`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.db_constraint) to `False` so that it does not make a constraint in the database but simply behaves like one. Also perhaps you should be using a [`UUIDField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield) here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `chain`:

```
from itertools import chain
search_filter_three = list(chain(results_query1, results_query2))
```